# Highlight given strings on a static HTML page with javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a static HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
ABC
XYZ
foo
bar
</body>
</html>
```

**Our question:** How can I put in buttons/links (?) to this single, static HTML file, so that the people that are visiting this page can **highlight** given predetermined strings after clicking on the button/link on the page? With javascript? But how?

UPDATE: Place "ABC" from the above HTML into `<big><b>` tags like: 
`<big><b>ABC</b></big>`

Comment: Have you tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KcX6A/1507/ ?

Comment: sorry, I don't meant selecting the text, I wanted to mean to make it more visible to the human eye! :D :\

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Any feedback on the answers so far?

Comment: soon! need a little time for it

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could do this.

### a. Using plain javascript, you can try this:

1- Have a variable with the strings you want highlighted.

```
highlight = ['ABC', 'XYZ', ... ];
```

2- Make the function that highlights the strings from the `highlight` variable

```
makeHL = function(strings) {
    // Get the HTML you want to search and replace strings on
    myHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;

    // Use string.replace to add <b></b> to them or another form of highlighting. 
    // You can use regular expressions here to make it more reliable.
    strings.forEach(function(str) {
        myHTML = myHTML.replace(str, '<b>' + str + '</b>');
    });

    // Reinsert your new html with the strings highlighted.
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = myHTML
}
```

3- When the user clicks your link or your button, just call `makeHL(highlights)`

### [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/45Lrv/)

Make sure that you include a Ecmascript5 shim such as [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) for use of `.forEach()` in browsers that don't support it.

### b. Using a library like jQuery, it's easier to work around browser incompatibilities:

1- Include [jQuery](http://jquery.com) before the rest of the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2- Have a variable with your replacements:

```
highlight = ['ABC', 'XYZ', ... ];
```

3- Make the function that highlights the strings from the `highlight` variable and bind it to the `click` event:

```
$('.makeHL').on('click', function() {
    // Get the HTML you want to search and replace strings on
    myHTML = $('body').html();

    // Use string.replace to add <b></b> to them or another form of highlighting. 
    // You can use regular expressions here to make it more reliable.
    $.each(highlight, function(i, str) {
        myHTML = myHTML.replace(str, '<b>' + str + '</b>');
    });
    // Reinsert your new html with the strings highlighted.    
    $('body').html(myHTML);
});
```

### [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/45Lrv/3/)

Comment: where does `myText` come from?

Comment: add a fiddle if u can.

Answer (score 2):

**[Working example](http://codepen.io/erethnor/pen/oqrdA)**

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <button class="highlight-text">Highlight "ABC"</button>
</p>

ABC
XYZ
foo
bar
```

**JS:**

```
(function(){
  function highlightText(textToHighlight) {
    var searchExpression;

    searchExpression = new RegExp('(' + textToHighlight + ')', 'g');

    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( searchExpression, '<b>$1</b>' );
  }

  document.querySelector('.highlight-text').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(){ highlightText('ABC'); },
    false
  );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/medda86/9g8XD/

html

```
ABC
XYZ
foo
bar
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Jquery

```
var predefinedStrings = new Array('ABC','bar');
var arrLength = predefinedStrings.length;
$('.button').click(function(){
    for (var i = 0;i < arrLength;i++){
        $('body').html($('body').html().replace(predefinedStrings[i],'<b>'+predefinedStrings[i]+'</b>'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Jquery javascript library

JQUERY

```
function highlight(word,content){
    //gi makes the replace recursive and case insensitive
    var regex = new RegExp( '(' +word+ ')', 'gi' );
    return content.replace( regex, bold );
}
function unhighlight(word,content){
    var regex = new RegExp( '(' +bold(word)+ ')', 'gi' );
    return content.replace( regex, strip );
}
function bold(word){
    return "<b>"+word+"</b>";
}
function strip(word){
    return word.replace("<b>","").replace("</b>","");
}

highlighted = null;
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("body").delegate(".highlight","click",function (e){
      var word = $(this).text();
      var container = $("body");
      var content = container.html();
      if(highlighted!=word){
        //this is optional if you would like to unhighlight prev selections
        content = unhighlight(highlighted,content);
        content = highlight(word,content);
        highlighted = word; 
        container.html(content);
      }
   });

});
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    ABC
    XYZ
    foo
    bar
    ABC
    XYZ foo FOO Bar ABC
    <button class="highlight">ABC</button>
    <button class="highlight">FOO</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Heres a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5G9YR/5/)